# How to find the n number of coordinates of circumference of circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles

Line AB has two coordinates  A = (1,3) and B = (1,6). How to find 10 uniform coordinates of a circumference of circle whoose radius is AB.

**Edit**

I tried  [this](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture6/circle.html) link but didn't get it.

Comment: Do you have the availability of $\sin \frac {n\pi} 5$ to solve the problem?

Comment: no i just have a coordinates.

Comment: check the edit for detail.

Comment: One of the great mathematicians was able to prove that the Fermat numbers $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ are the numbers of sides of regular polygons that are constructable using ruler and compass... So $5=2^{2^1}+1$ is constructable, and applying angle bisectors should get the side count up to $10$...

Comment: Having said that, I don't actually know the process of the construction...

Comment: Have you checked the link in the edit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11454/discussion-between-user2749218-and-abiessu)

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the center and $B$ is a point on the circumference, you have the radius $r=|AB|$, which here is $3$.  To get $10$ equally spaced points, you can do $(x_i,y_i)=(1+3\cos \frac {i\pi}5, 3+3\sin \frac {i\pi}5)$ where the first term is the coordinate of $A$, the $3$ multiplying the trig functions is the radius, and  $i$ ranges from $0$ through $9$

Comment: The OP said $\sin \frac {n\pi}5$ was not available when I asked...